# Codeigniter not logging

Tags: codeigniter, logging, error-handling, message

I can't seem to figure out why codeigniter isn't logging my log_messages

In Config:

```
$config['log_threshold'] = 4;
$config['log_path'] = '/var/log/mydlp.log';
```

In script:

```
log_message('error','here');
```

File location:

```
-rw-rw-rw- 1 root  root    0 2012-12-05 13:10 mydlp.log
```

I'm not getting anything when I get to the log message.

Here's my directory structure for /var and /var/log

```
 drwxr-xr-x  6 root root  4096 2012-12-05 13:10 log
 drwxr-xr-x  14 root root  4096 2012-01-04 14:38 var
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`$config['log_path']` is supposed to be a path to a directory, not a file. CI writes its own files in the format `log-2012-12-05.php`. Try a path to a directory, and make sure to include a trailing slash.

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Error Logging Directory Path
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Leave this BLANK unless you would like to set something other than the default
| application/logs/ folder. Use a full server path with trailing slash.
|
*/
$config['log_path'] = '/var/log/ci_logs/';
```

Comment: Is 755 ok for the permissions or does it need to be 777?

Comment: looks like 755 didn't work, I had to switch it to 777, but I'm assuming that's cause the folder was created by root. I'll change it to the server then it should work 755. Thanks tons.

Comment: Yeah I think I had to do the same and just used 777.

Comment: +1 also had to use 777 remotely but 755 worked locally. I believe it's a user group issue where my remote server has a different apache user than that of the directory owner.

Comment: Previously wondering why it works locally but not in the server, so I tried 777 file permission and it works in remote server.

Comment: Make sure the log_path is a full path.

Comment: Make sure the log_path is a full path and writable. E.g. C:\wamp64\www\your_project\application\logs/.  This worked for me

Answer (score 3):

the problem is SELinux check this post.

you try this:

```
# Ownership
sudo chown apache:apache -R /data/www/html/sites/mysite
cd /data/www/html/sites/mysite

# File permissions, recursive
find . -type f -exec chmod 0644 {} \;

# Dir permissions, recursive
find . -type d -exec chmod 0755 {} \;

# SELinux serve files off Apache, resursive
sudo chcon -t httpd_sys_content_t /data/www/html/sites/mysite -R

# Allow write only to specific dirs
sudo chcon -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t /data/www/html/sites/mysite/logs -R
sudo chcon -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t /data/www/html/sites/mysite/uploads -R
```

https://blog.lysender.com/2015/07/centos-7-selinux-php-apache-cannot-writeaccess-file-no-matter-what/